# How to change default /tmp to /home/user/tmp

Tags: linux, java, environment-variables, tmp

Is there an environment variable to set the temporary directory on debian based systems?

I have a java applet that uses that environement variable and it's getting confused when launching two instances of the same applet.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192426/6622

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am unsure if the java applet will actually look at the environment variables before it starts, but what you can do it edit /etc/profile and add the following lines:

```shell
if [[ -O /home/$USER/tmp && -d /home/$USER/tmp ]]; then
        TMPDIR=/home/$USER/tmp
else
        # You may wish to remove this line, it is there in case
        # a user has put a file 'tmp' in there directory or a
        rm -rf /home/$USER/tmp 2> /dev/null
        mkdir -p /home/$USER/tmp
        TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d /home/$USER/tmp/XXXX)
fi

TMP=$TMPDIR
TEMP=$TMPDIR

export TMPDIR TMP TEMP
```

To make it a true tmp directory (as in the files go away when the session is ended, you'll want to edit the user's .bash_logout as well as the skeleton .bash_logout (/etc/skel/.bash_logout) to include the following:

```
if [ -O $TMPDIR && -d $TMPDIR ]; then
        rm -rf $TMPDIR/*
fi
```

The logout portion is dangerous is the variable doesn't get set and your logged in as root! I wouldn't add this to the root account or anyone that is a member of the wheel group! Proceed at your own caution.

Comment: I wouldn't put the cleanup into .bash_logout at all - what happens if they open up two sessions and log out of one?

Use tmpwatch. :)

Comment: That is a much better cleanup solution, thanks for adding that. :)

Comment: NB: the `tmpwatch` command does not exists on BSD (e.g. OSX) version of unix, for anyone going for portability.  My CentOS boxes have it though. :)

Answer (score 9):

The file you are looking for is:

```
/etc/environment
```

You have to set the TEMP variable like:

```
TEMP=/home/user/tmp
```

Comment: And even `export TEMP=/home/user/tmp`

Comment: @Fedir that is in the shell, yes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `/home/user/tmp` to be cleaned on reboot, I suggest you add an `@reboot` job to the user's personal `crontab`.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses the system property `java.io.tmpdir` to configure the temporary directory. A reasonable JRE will set that to a sensible value based on the system if not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked when i was trying to install a jar file using java.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/apps/prod/tmp"
```

I use a Red Hat Linux. `/apps/prod/tmp` being the new folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
export TMPDIR=/path/to/desired/tmp
```

Use that before running desired command.

Comment: This will only print the text `TMPDIR=/path/to/desired/tmp`. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry about that. Had to be `export` not `echo`. It really saved me a ot of pain. Some process was writing extremely large files to /tmp and I didn't want to allocate the space just for it. Or, reboot.

Comment: This will work for Scripts using `mktemp`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, I would use the [tmpfile()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/tmpfile.html) call for a posix system, which would avoid the collision. So I would look for a similar Java call before trying to implement it myself, if you haven't already.

Comment: This assumes he is the one developing the application

Comment: TrueDuality: Ah, my mistake

Comment: Java has `java.io.File.createTempFile`. Now with added secure RNG.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=1dab2wir99_201&_afrLoop=305930829027924#SYMPTOM

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=<local path>"
```

Eg:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/user/tmp"
```